# Why does "pstack" only print one thread's content?

Tags: linux, multithreading, go, gdb, pstack

My `OS` is `RHEL 7`, and I run a simple `Go` program:

```
package main

import (
    "time"
)

func main() {
    time.Sleep(1000 * time.Second)
}
```

During its running, I check the thread count of process:

```
# cat /proc/13858/status | grep Thread
Threads:        5
```

While using the `pstack` command shipped on `RHEL`, it only prints one thread's stack:

```
# pstack 13858
Thread 1 (process 13858):
#0  runtime.futex () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sys_linux_amd64.s:307
#1  0x0000000000422580 in runtime.futexsleep (addr=0x4c7af8 <runtime.timers+24>, val=0, ns=999999997446) at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os1_linux.go:57
#2  0x000000000040b07b in runtime.notetsleep_internal (n=0x4c7af8 <runtime.timers+24>, ns=999999997446, ~r2=255) at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/lock_futex.go:174
#3  0x000000000040b1e6 in runtime.notetsleepg (n=0x4c7af8 <runtime.timers+24>, ns=999999997446, ~r2=false) at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/lock_futex.go:206
#4  0x000000000043e5de in runtime.timerproc () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/time.go:209
#5  0x0000000000451001 in runtime.goexit () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1998
#6  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Why does `pstack` only print one thread's content?

P.S.: The `pstack` script is here:

```
#!/bin/sh

if test $# -ne 1; then
    echo "Usage: `basename $0 .sh` <process-id>" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

if test ! -r /proc/$1; then
    echo "Process $1 not found." 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

# GDB doesn't allow "thread apply all bt" when the process isn't
# threaded; need to peek at the process to determine if that or the
# simpler "bt" should be used.

backtrace="bt"
if test -d /proc/$1/task ; then
    # Newer kernel; has a task/ directory.
    if test `/bin/ls /proc/$1/task | /usr/bin/wc -l` -gt 1 2>/dev/null ; then
        backtrace="thread apply all bt"
    fi
elif test -f /proc/$1/maps ; then
    # Older kernel; go by it loading libpthread.
    if /bin/grep -e libpthread /proc/$1/maps > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
        backtrace="thread apply all bt"
    fi
fi

GDB=${GDB:-/usr/bin/gdb}

# Run GDB, strip out unwanted noise.
# --readnever is no longer used since .gdb_index is now in use.
$GDB --quiet -nx $GDBARGS /proc/$1/exe $1 <<EOF 2>&1 |
set width 0
set height 0
set pagination no
$backtrace
EOF
/bin/sed -n \
    -e 's/^\((gdb) \)*//' \
    -e '/^#/p' \
    -e '/^Thread/p'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pstack uses gdb. This is a quote from golang doc (https://golang.org/doc/gdb):

> GDB does not understand Go programs well. The stack management,
>   threading, and runtime contain aspects that differ enough from the
>   execution model GDB expects that they can confuse the debugger, even
>   when the program is compiled with gccgo. As a consequence, although
>   GDB can be useful in some situations, it is not a reliable debugger
>   for Go programs, particularly heavily concurrent ones.

4 out of 5 threads that you see in /proc are created even before you program enters main. I assume that golang runtime creates them.

> Why does pstack only print one thread's content?

Judging from output of strace for gdb I see that `gdb` actually tries to attach to them but after something goes wrong and `gdb` does not try to inspect these threads. These are syscalls that gdb issued for these runtime threads but due to unknown reason decided stopped investigating them immediately:

```
5072  ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, 5023, 0, 0) = 0
5072  --- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
5072  rt_sigreturn(0x11)                = 0
5072  ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, 5024, 0, 0) = 0
5072  --- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
5072  rt_sigreturn(0x11)                = 0
5072  ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, 5025, 0, 0) = 0
5072  --- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
5072  rt_sigreturn(0x11)                = 0
```

However you can inspect them yourself. It seems that these threads belong to golang runtime

```
$ pstack 5094
Thread 1 (process 5094):
#0  0x0000000000459243 in runtime.futex ()
#1  0x00000000004271e0 in runtime.futexsleep ()
#2  0x000000000040d55b in runtime.notetsleep_internal ()
#3  0x000000000040d64b in runtime.notetsleep ()
#4  0x0000000000435677 in runtime.sysmon ()
#5  0x000000000042e6cc in runtime.mstart1 ()
#6  0x000000000042e5d2 in runtime.mstart ()
#7  0x00000000004592b7 in runtime.clone ()
#8  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

$ pstack 5095
Thread 1 (process 5095):
#0  0x0000000000459243 in runtime.futex ()
#1  0x0000000000427143 in runtime.futexsleep ()
#2  0x000000000040d3f4 in runtime.notesleep ()
#3  0x000000000042f6eb in runtime.stopm ()
#4  0x0000000000430a79 in runtime.findrunnable ()
#5  0x00000000004310ff in runtime.schedule ()
#6  0x000000000043139b in runtime.park_m ()
#7  0x0000000000455acb in runtime.mcall ()
#8  0x000000c820021500 in ?? ()
#9  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

$ pstack 5096
Thread 1 (process 5096):
#0  0x0000000000459243 in runtime.futex ()
#1  0x0000000000427143 in runtime.futexsleep ()
#2  0x000000000040d3f4 in runtime.notesleep ()
#3  0x000000000042f6eb in runtime.stopm ()
#4  0x000000000042fff7 in runtime.startlockedm ()
#5  0x0000000000431147 in runtime.schedule ()
#6  0x000000000043139b in runtime.park_m ()
#7  0x0000000000455acb in runtime.mcall ()
#8  0x000000c820020000 in ?? ()
```

---

**Update for gdb 8.0**

pstack that uses gdb 8.0 correctly prints backtraces for all threas. The command looks like:

```
$ GDB=$HOME/bin/gdb pstack  $(pidof main)
```

And here is its output (shortened):

```
$ GDB=$HOME/bin/gdb pstack  $(pidof main) | egrep "^Thread"
Thread 4 (LWP 18335):
Thread 3 (LWP 18334):
Thread 2 (LWP 18333):
Thread 1 (LWP 18332):
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! If possible, could u elaborate how to use `strace` to check `gdb`? Thx!

Comment: This way I see that gdb does: `strace -f -v -o gdb.txt gdb --batch -ex "thread apply all bt" test_pid <PID>`. test_pid is a golang program. By the way, Tom Tromey who is a developer of gdb answers questions on this site. So possibly wait for an answer from him

Answer (score 0):

When you're passing LWP/thread id to `pstack` you get a stack of that thread only. Try to pass a PID of the process to `pstack` and you'll get stacks of all its threads. You may get a PID or Tgid (thread group id) of the process: `cat /proc/13858/status | grep Tgid`. To get all LWPs created by your process you may run `ps -L <PID>`

Comment: Yes, `13858` is just the PID, so I am very confused. Thx!

Comment: Yes, when GDB is started with a given PID of your Go application it somehow gets confused and `info threads` doesn't provide information about other threads. So your question actually about the issue with GDB and needs further investigation.

Comment: @Mikhail Volskiy, Mikhail, nice to me you here. We used to work together in PS

Comment: @ Sergei Kurenkov, Me too, actually it's a small world.